# How to identify class type to cast a shared_ptr to that type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a class hierarchy and I want get shared from this and cast it to the specific class type. So I want this:

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> getSharedFromThis()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<A>(shared_from_this());
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> getSharedFromThis()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<B>(shared_from_this());
    }
};
```

In superclass I can write a templated variant but it is still not cool:

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> getSharedFromThis()
{
    return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(shared_from_this());
}
```

How can I make it generic so that it will understand that it is in class `B` and cast to `B` the `shared_ptr` and now write the same logic in 100 classes that are in the same hierarchy.

Comment: Is using the CRTP a reasonable solution?

Comment: @TartanLlama with CRTP I am going to inherit from the same class in all hierarchy.

Comment: BTW, if you want to use `std::shared_from_this`, then you have to derive your class from `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: @Nawaz it is done in my code :)

Comment: It does not hurt if you add this to your code-snippet here, otherwise the current form will confuse a lot of readers, and mislead newbies.

Comment: Agreed. See my change above.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for *[covariant return type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type)* wise [smart pointers](https://github.com/CppCodeReviewers/Covariant-Return-Types-and-Smart-Pointers). That would be a nice feature, but you cant do it. The only way it could work is having a hierarchical relationship between `shared_ptr<A>` and `shared_ptr<B>`, which will not be the case in any near future.

You must either stick to the parent class template or use a wrapper object able to implement the covariant return type paradigm (that would mean careful declarations and possible mistakes due to copypasta).

`std::enable_shared_from_this` is not used correctly in your example since it is a templated class.

Be careful to use a `dynamic_pointer_cast` if the getter lays in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your key problem is deducing the type which called the templated `getSharedFromThis()`. Since the member function is implemented in a base class, it doesn't have any trace of derived class calling it - unless that is somehow specified. Using a non-member function calling the base function will take care of that neatly:

```
template <typename T>
auto getSharedFromThis(T& object) -> decltype(object.template getSharedFromThis<T>()) {
    return object.template getSharedFromThis<T>());
}
```

This way there is no need to write anything for any of derived classes to get a `getSharedFromThis()` function yielding an appropriately type `std::shared_ptr<T>`. As a bonus, a similar hierarchy with a base exposing a `getSharedFromThis()` function can use the same function. You might want to overload the function with a pointer type so you can use `getSharedFromThis(this)` instead of `getSharedFromThis(*this)` in member functions.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. What is `getSharedFromThis` that you call in the body of the template function. Please explain you code a bit.

Comment: @Narek: the idea is to have a base-class function template `getSharedFromThis()` which is actually exactly the member you wrote (labeled "not cool") and to use this member from a non-member function template. The implementation of my non-member function just calls that base member (the only quirky thing here is the odd `template` keyword which is needed because `getSharedFromThis` is a dependent name).